# Error for create data frame ts with zoo package

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, zoo

I try to create a data frame for temporal series analysis with zoo package with my especific case, but doen't work, my artificial script is:

```
require(zoo)

TSdata<-NULL

TSdata$id<-seq(1:30) ##ID

TSdata$Date<-seq(as.Date("2015/1/15"), by = 15, length.out = 30) ## Vector of date

TSdata$rain<-rnorm(30,mean=125)#Covariate 1

TSdata$temp<-rnorm(30,mean=32.6) #Covariate 2

TSdata$y<-rpois(30,lambda=15) # Response variable

TSdata<-as.data.frame(TSdata) ## Convert to data frame

## Create temporal series object

ts.data <- read.zoo(text="TSdata", format="%Y/%m/%d", index.column = 2) ## Here the problem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right solution is to given by the other answer. As another option you can use the constructor `zoo`:

```
zoo(x=TSdata[,!grepl("Date",colnames(TSdata))],
    order.by = TSdata$Date)

#            id     rain     temp  y
# 2015-01-15  1 122.6501 32.46969 18
# 2015-01-30  2 124.4833 31.46569 13
# 2015-02-14  3 125.2021 33.05852 13
```

Comment: In fact, `read.zoo` CAN create a `zoo` object from a `data.frame`. I'll explain this in a separate answer. Of course, your solution works as well...

Comment: Yes, exactly. But you can get the additional convenience tools of `read.zoo`: Converting characters to Date or POSIXct, merging time/date if its spread across several columns, splitting, aggregating, etc. In this particular case, these are all unnecessary, though.

Comment: @AchimZeileis thank you for the explanation. Thank you also for your contribution to the community with the unavailable `zoo` package.

Comment: :-) Thanks, glad if it's useful!

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in your code: (1) If you want create a `zoo` object with `read.zoo()` from a `data.frame`, then you simply need to supply the object `TSdata` and not a character string with its name `"TSdata"`. (2) The `format` is not `"%Y/%m/%d"`. But as the index is already a `Date` column, no `format` needs to be supplied anyways.

Simply do:

```
read.zoo(TSdata, index.column = 2)
##            id     rain     temp  y
## 2015-01-15  1 125.3376 32.91936 13
## 2015-01-30  2 125.2048 32.71199 17
## 2015-02-14  3 125.7443 32.74698 17
## ...
```